# Is it possible to combine 2 opengl EXTERNAL_OES texture together?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am just wondering if it is possible to combine 2 GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture and access them at the same time in the fragment shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bind it as a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture
2. Use uniform **samplerExternalOES** tex0 and tex1 instead of **sampler2D**

Comment: Yea i found out about it too. Thanks. But anyway i have another question. How can i make each External texture draw on each half of the screen left and right? I tried several matrix multiplication and it is not working.

Comment: @HoWeiLip Are you saying that for example, the left side of screen is filled by texture A and the right side is a texture b?

Comment: How exactly does the program know which is tex0 and tex1? I have the same question as @HoWeiLip

Comment: @MohammadSheraj once you know the texture name(id), you can bind it 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture_id_for_tex0);
glUniform1i(_textureUniform, “tex0”);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,  texture_id_for_tex1);
glUniform1i(_textureUniform, “tex1”);